# How many four-digit odd numbers are there in which there is exactly one digit $4$ and exactly one digit $5$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many four-digit odd numbers are there in which: b) there is exactly one digit $4$ and exactly one digit $5$?

My try:
$1×2×8×4=64$

$7×1×2×4=56$

$7×8×1×1=56$

$7×1×8×1=56$

$1×8×8×1=64$

$64×2+56×3=296$

But apparently it's wrong, the right answer is $360$, and idk what I did wrong.

Comment: Please could you explain your reasoning more clearly?

Comment: **Basic approach.** You'll need to consider nine different cases: $54\_\_, 5\_4\_, 45\_\_, \_54\_, 4\_5\_, \_45\_, 4\_\_5, \_4\_5, \_\_45$. If the leading digit is neither $4$ nor $5$, you can't fill it with a $0$. If the tailing digit is not a $5$, you can only fill it with a $1, 3, 7, 9$. An empty middle digit can be anything. ¶ But yes, as @legionwhale says, you should explain where each of those products came from. It's not clear how you arrived at each of those factors.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider two cases based on the last digit of the number.

- Ends in $5$: 
   We choose the place for the digit $4$ in $3$ ways because it can't be at the end. The last place is occupied by the digit $5$, so there are $2$ free places left. For each of them, we can place any digit other than $4$ and $5$, and there are $8$ such digits. We get $3\cdot8\cdot8$.
- Number does not end in $5$: 
  Again, we choose the place for the digit $4$ in $3$ ways, but this time we can place the digit $5$ in $2$ ways (it cannot be at the end). There is a place left at the end with $4$ possibilities ($1, 3, 7, 9$) and some other place with $8$ possibilities (any digit different from $4$ or $5$). We get $3\cdot2\cdot4\cdot8$.

But that's not all because we need to subtract the wrong cases where the number starts with zero, e.g., $0543$, because we have also counted those. You can do this in the same way as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to Michal's elegant approach.

We can reduce the problem to four cases:

*The thousands digit is $4$ and the units digit is $5$*: Since we are allowed to use $4$ exactly once and $5$ exactly once, we have eight choices for the hundreds digit and eight choices for the tens digit.  Therefore, there are $1 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 1$ such numbers.

*The thousands digit is not $4$ and the units digit is $5$*:  There are seven choices for the thousands digit since it cannot be $4$, $5$, or $0$.  There are two ways to place the four.  The remaining digit can be filled in eight ways.  Hence, there are $7 \cdot 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 1$ such numbers.

*The thousands digit is $4$ or $5$ and the units digit is not $5$*:  There are two choices for the thousands digit, two ways to place the remaining digit from the set $\{4, 5\}$, four choices for the units digit since it must be an odd number other than $5$, and eight choices for the remaining digit.  Hence, there are $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 4$ such numbers.

*The thousands digit is neither $4$ nor $5$ and the units digit is not $5$*:  There are seven choices for the leading digit, four choices for the units digit since it must be an odd digit other than $5$, and $2!$ ways to arrange the $4$ and $5$ in the hundreds and tens places.  Hence, there are $7 \cdot 2! \cdot 4$ such numbers.

*Total*:  Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of four-digit odd positive integers in which the digits $4$ and $5$ each occur exactly once is
$$1 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 + 7 \cdot 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 4 + 7 \cdot 2! \cdot 4 = 360$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method based on omitting $4$ and $5$ and reinserting them

- Ignoring $4$ and $5$, there are $7*8*8*4$ odd numbers
- Two digits have to be replaced by $4$ and $5$
- The replacement chart is given below. **$1's$ in the chart indicate using $4$ or $5$** *Note that $4$ and $5$ can be interchanged only if $5$ is not the last (odd) digit*

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 
Available & 7 & 8 & 8 & 4 & Arrangements \\ \hline 
Used & 1 & 1 & 8 & 4 & 2*8*4=64 \\ \hline
Used & 1 & 8 & 1 & 4 & 2*8*4=64 \\ \hline
Used & 1 & 8 & 8 & 1 & 1*8*8=64 \\ \hline
Used & 7 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2*7*4=56 \\ \hline
Used & 7 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 1*7*8=56 \\ \hline
Used & 7 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 1*7*8=56 \\ \hline \end{array}$

Total arrangements $ = 3(64+56) = 360$

Note how the bothersome zero gets settled right at the start.